# why can't I navigate to a page in the webbrowser control during runtime?

Tags: c#, browser, webbrowser-control

When I do something like this

```
webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();  
webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://google.com");  
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com");
```

all I get is a blank window.
when I step through this webBrowser1.Url stays = null after the second statement has executed. Why is that?

if I set the url property before I compile the web site loads correctly when I open the form.
So why can't I load a site dynamically?

Comment: You are using this code in form load event correct?

Comment: It works in my code.  Is there more going on that you didn't post?

Comment: Which webbrowser control? Winforms? WPF?

Comment: I had it in the constructor and it worked when I moved it out.  I now call a function after the form loads to set the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had it in the constructor and it worked when I moved it out. I now call a function after the form loads to set the control

Answer (score 2):

If you've added the Web Browser control at design-time, you don't need to instantiate it in code (InitializeComponent will take care of that for you).

Remove this line:

```
webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
```

...and it should work fine for you.

If you are declaring the control in code, then you must add it to the visual tree of the parent form:

```
this.Controls.Add(webBrowser1);
```

where "this" refers to your form.

Answer (score 0):

`WebBrowser` works asynchronously so you have to subscribe to `WebBrowser.Navigated` and wait until it will navigate to URL given and render resulting HTML